# Flatten a grouped list and sort according to frequency of items (production planning)

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, linq, sorting

I have the following grouped data structure (for a production planning system):

```
Product A | Variant A | Color Red: 10 items 
Product A | Variant A | Color Blue: 5 items
Product A | Variant B | Color Red: 2 items
Product B | Variant C | Color Black: 5 items 
...
```

I have for example 500 products to produce, and 50 production slots per week.

I need to fill the slots according to the amount of items per grouping.

How can I create a sequential list out of this grouping, that ensures that product groupings with a higher count get produced more frequently ?

It is necessary to have a good range of products in the store. Therefore it is not possible to produce for example 50 items of Variant A in a week, and then 50 of the next variant. The production planning system should ensure that there is a good range of products after for example 4 weeks of production, but the more popular ones should also receive more production than the others.

I use C# to implement the system, but any language / algorithm idea would be very helpful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need a precise specification for "a good range of products". How many in minimum and maximum and how do these numbers depend on the popularity. How is *popularity* defined? and so on... then only you can start to develop an algorithm. Searching for "production planning algorithms" in your favorite search engine, will give you many results. Some use genetic algorithms, heuristics, and algorithms with strange acronyms. Mostly academic papers. If fear that there is no simple answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply! In this case we can derive the popularity from the amount of ordered items. In terms of the range: I just wanted to explain why it necessary to distribute the orders. I will have a look a the search results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward method would be to  pro-rate the 50 available slots based on the proportion of every individual item to produce within the total number of items to produce (sum across all groups).

I.E.:  let us assume these 4 lines are all the items to produce at this time.

```
Product A | Variant A | Color Red: 32 items 
Product A | Variant A | Color Blue: 15 items
Product A | Variant B | Color Red: 12 items
Product B | Variant C | Color Black: 5 items
```

The groups have to be sorted in descending order so as to ensure the groups with the highest number get allocated for production first.

The total number of items to produce is then 32+15+12+5 = 64.

The allocation of the available slots based on the each group ratio (weight) will then be:

```
50* 32/64 =25 items for the 1st group
50* 15/64 = 11 items for the 2nd group
50* 12/64 =  9  items for the 3rd group
50* 5/64 =3  items for the 4th group
```

Then the remainder (which is due to rounding) can be distributed either recursively or throughout the rest of the group items.

Here is implementation with recursive remainder allocation up until it is fully allocated with the ratios updated on every round of recursion based on the remaining need for each group.

```
 public class Group
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Variant { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int NeededToProduce { get; set; }
    public int AllocatedForProd { get; set; }

}

public class Calculation
{
    public Calculation()
    {
        AllocateProdSlots(this._prodSlots, this._groups);
    }
    private List<Group> _groups = new List<Group>()
    {
        new Group () {Product = "A", Variant = "A", Color = "Red",  NeededToProduce = 32  , AllocatedForProd = 0},
        new Group () {Product = "A", Variant = "A", Color = "Blue", NeededToProduce = 15 , AllocatedForProd = 0},
        new Group () {Product = "A", Variant = "B", Color = "Red",  NeededToProduce = 12 , AllocatedForProd = 0},
        new Group () {Product = "B", Variant = "C", Color = "Black", NeededToProduce = 5 , AllocatedForProd = 0},

    }  ;

    private int _prodSlots = 50;


    private void AllocateProdSlots( int remainingProdSlots, List<Group> groups)
    {

        groups = groups.OrderByDescending(g => g.NeededToProduce).ToList<Group>();  
                   
        decimal total = GetTotalNumberOfItemsInGroups();
        
        foreach(var g in groups)
        {
            if (remainingProdSlots > 0)
            {

                int remainingNeedGroup = g.NeededToProduce - g.AllocatedForProd;
                int allocation = Decimal.ToInt32( remainingNeedGroup / total * remainingProdSlots);

                if (allocation <= remainingNeedGroup)
                    g.AllocatedForProd += allocation;
                else g.AllocatedForProd += remainingNeedGroup;

                if (allocation == 0 && remainingNeedGroup > 0 && remainingProdSlots > 0) //rounded down
                {
                    g.AllocatedForProd += 1;     //give such group 1 slot
                    allocation = 1;
                }

                remainingProdSlots -= allocation;
                Console.WriteLine($" NumberToProduce {g.NeededToProduce}; AllocatedForProd {g.AllocatedForProd}; remainingProdSlots {remainingProdSlots};");
            }
            else break;

        }

        if (remainingProdSlots > 0) //we still have a remainder after the above allocation round - call another round to sart on the remaining slots
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Remainder to be allocated in the next round {remainingProdSlots}");
            AllocateProdSlots(remainingProdSlots, groups);
        }
         

    }

    private decimal GetTotalNumberOfItemsInGroups()
    {
        return _groups.Sum(g => g.NeededToProduce);
    }


}
```

Comment: Nice approach! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> The groups have to be sorted in descending order so as to ensure the groups with the highest number get allocated for production first.

I don't see groups or Products in your original sequence. You don't have "Groups with their Variants" I only see a flat "Product-Variant" sequence that that is ordered according to the name of the Product. To me your input sequence seems the result of an inner join.

If you want the products with the highest "number" first, just sort them by "number".

```
 // get your input sequence with ProductName, VariantName, Color, ItemCount:
IEnumerable<...> products = ...

// order them, the highest ItemCount first:
var productsOrderedByDescendingItemCount = products.OrderByDescending(
    product => product.ItemCount);
```